# Show errors for all files in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I've got a large C project in VSCode.
If there are errors in the current file, they will show in the Problems panel. However, they aren't shown for every file.

Is there any way to show all errors and warnings for all files, rather than just opened files?